# Why are all map values being updated on each iteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make a method that takes in any number of sqlalchemy models and determines whether or not they have the same attributes. The method also takes in `cols_to_ignore` which is an array of strings representing column names to ignore.

To do this, I make a map with the attributes of the model and iterate over each model, adding each column value to the set I store as the values in the map. The map is then returned to another method that checks that the length of any given map value is 1, meaning all attributes were the same, or more than one meaning that the models submitted have different attribute values.

The problem I'm having is that the code currently updates the value at each key rather than just the key with the specific column name.

For example, running the code with the following models (represented by json here) `{birthMonth: 'January', birthYear: 1990}, {birthMonth: 'March', birthYear: 1990}` should result in the following map:

`{'birthMonth':{January, March}, 'birthYear':{1990}}`

But instead results in:

`{'birthMonth': {January,1990,March}, birthYear: {January,1990,March}}`

Here is my code:

```py
def have_same_attributes(cols_to_ignore, *models):
    if not all_same_model(models):
        raise ValueError('Types of models must all match')
    attribute_map = dict.fromkeys(models[0].__table__.columns.keys(), set())
    for model in models:
        for key in model.__table__.columns.keys():
            if key in cols_to_ignore:
                continue
            attribute_map[key].add(getattr(model, key))
    return attribute_map
    for value in attribute_map.values():
        if(len(value)>1):
            return False
    return True
```

`all_same_model(models)` verifies that all of the models submitted to the method are of the same type.

I feel like it's something simple that I'm not seeing but I've been at this for a while now with no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `return attribute_map` seems to be in a wrong position, given the loop underneath never executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variant on the common `[[]]*10` bug: `dict.fromkeys` uses the single **object** supplied as the value for every key, so there is just the one `set` being updated.  (How would it know how to recreate a “similar” `set` object?)

Answer (score 0):

From the answer provided by Davis Herring I was able to refactor the code to avoid using the dict.fromkeys method and get it working. This is the updated code which works now.

```
def have_same_attributes(cols_to_ignore, *models):
    if not all_same_model(models):
        raise ValueError('Types of models must all match')
    attribute_map = dict()
    for key in models[0].__table__.columns.keys():
        if key in cols_to_ignore:
            continue
        attribute_map[key] = set()
    for model in models:
        for key in model.__table__.columns.keys():
            if key in cols_to_ignore:
                continue
            attribute_map[key].add(getattr(model, key))
            if(len(attribute_map[key])>1):
                return False
    return True
```